# Rational solutions to $x^4+y^4=cz^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

Suppose $c\neq 1$ is a squarefree number, and consider the curve $x^4+y^4=cz^2$. How can I find rational points on this curve?

What I really want to know is how to transform this into an elliptic curve. I'm confused for the following reason: this curve has three variables, while elliptic curves have two variables.

Comment: To use the solution of the equation.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1051335_pythagorean_triple   $$x^2+y^2=cz^2$$  And then solve the system when  $x=x^2$      and  $y=y^2$  .

Answer (score 3):

From,

$$x^4+y^4=cz^2\tag1$$

If you do the following change of variables,

$$X = -\frac{4 x^{2} y^{2}}{z^{2}}\tag2$$ 
$$Y = \frac{4 xy(x^{4} - y^{4})}{z^{3}}\tag3$$

then you can check that,

$$Y^2 = X^3 - 4c^2X\tag4$$

which is an elliptic curve in Weierstrass form, and is famously related to [congruent numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number).

Comment: Thank you! But I am curious: what is the rank of this elliptic curve?

Comment: @Josh [OEIS A184982](https://oeis.org/A184982) has a list of small $c$ which afford an infinite number of inequivalent nonzero solutions for the equation $x^4 + y^4 = c z^2$. According to $\S 6.5$ of Henri Cohen's [Number Theory, Vol I](http://www.amazon.com/Number-Theory-Diophantine-Equations-Mathematics/dp/0387499229) , for $3 \le c \le 10001$, the rank of all these elliptic curve which afford infinite number of solutions are all $2$.

Comment: @Jesper: If $(1)$ is solvable in the rationals for some rational $c$, then your transformations $(2), (3)$ guarantee that so is $(4)$. But just to be clear, it doesn't go the other way round, correct? That is, if $(4)$ is solvable, then that does ***not*** mean that so is $(1)$. For example, $$X^3-25X = Y^2$$ has a small solution $X,Y = 41^2/12^2,\,  62279/12^3$. However, I cannot rationally derive $x,y$ from $X,Y$ to solve $$x^4+y^4 = \tfrac{5}{2}c^2$$ Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Never mind, I managed to answer my question. The sequence of solvable $m$ for $a^4+b^4 = mc^2$ starts as, $$m=17, 82, 97, 113, 193, 257, 274,\dots$$ while that for $x^3-n^2x = y^2$ is $$n = 5, 6, 7, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 29, 30, 31, 34, 37,\dots$$ and hence are obviously not the same.  :)  But all $2m$ appear in the latter list.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused too, by the same reasons you said . Anyway, I give you here two comments (not exactly an answer).

1) The diophantine equation $ax^4+by^4=cz^2; (x, y)=1$ has a long history and there is a lot of cases of impossibility that have been established (Nagell among others) so take $c\neq 1$ could be too general. Another thing is to calculate $a^4+b^4$, say equal to n, so you get a solution (a, b,1) if n is squarefree or a better solution if does not. (of either, $x^4+y^4=nz^2$ or $x^4+y^4=cz^2$ where c divides n).

2)(*Concerning your goal to find out an elliptic curve that works*) It is known the quartic $$F(x,y)=ax^4+4bx^3y+6cx^2y^2+4dxy^3+ey^4$$ has as invariants $g_2=ae-4bd+3c^2$ and
$g_3$=det$\begin{pmatrix} a & b& c \\ b&c &d \\c &d &e  \\ \end{pmatrix}$, and the quartic 
$$y^2=x^4+6cx^2+4dx+e$$  (where you have divided $F(x,y)$ by $y^4$ and maked $a=1;b=0)$) is birational equivalent to the cubic $$t^2=4s^3-g_2s-g_3$$ via the function
$(2x(s+c), y)\to (t-d, 2s-x^2-c)$.

Searching of applying this, $x^4+y^4$ has invariants $g_2=g_3=0$ and this curve would be equivalent to the cubic $t^2=4s^3$ which clearly is not elliptic.

I repeat, I am confused too and I give you just a hint maybe worthless here, just wishing  to assist you in your question.